# convert nested dictionaries to list of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I’ve a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
  "g": {
    "o": {}
  },
  "h": {
    "p": {}
  },
  "e": {
    "v": {},
    "m": {
      "s": {}
    }
  },
  "f": {
    "n": {}
  },
  "a": {
    "i": {}
  },
  "d": {
    "u": {},
    "l": {
      "r": {}
    }
  },
  "b": {
    "j": {}
  },
  "c": {
    "t": {},
    "k": {
      "q": {
        "z": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a fast way of convert it to a list of lists to get the following output:

```
 [g, o]
 [h, p]
 [e, v]
 [e, m, s]
 [f, n]
 [a, i]
 [d, u]
 [d, l, r]
 [b, j]
 [c, t]
 [c, k, q, z]
```

we stop when we encounter an empty dictionary. for example, we start with "g", it has child "o" which in turn has no children, the list thus consists of "g" and "o".

another example: starting with "e", children are "v" and "m" and "m" has "s". Thus we have two lists: one with "e" and "v" and another with "e", "v" and "m".

I tried creating a recursive function but unfortunately, it didnt turn out well.

Comment: What work have you done on this problem so far? Have you found a slow way to do that conversion? Do you intend for those lists in your final example to be inside a single, larger list?

Comment: yes. loopy way. ill update OP with what i have.

Comment: I don't get the logic of your conversion. How are [e, v] and [e, m, s] subdicts of your dict?

Comment: stop when you encounter an empty dictionary

Comment: ive updated the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty fast, using a recursive function with generators:

```
def paths(tree, cur=()):
    if not tree:
        yield cur
    else:
        for n, s in tree.items():
            for path in paths(s, cur+(n,)):
                yield list(path)
```

To use:

```
list(paths(your_dict))
```